# Python, PyQt: Find font file name from postscript name

Tags: python, qt, fonts, pyqt

I am handing off font data from one application to another, and unfortunately the first application is only able to give me "postscript" font names and nothing else. What I need is to find the filename on disk of the postscript font name. For example I have the postscript name "ZoomlaYingXing-A024" which is called "ZhuLang Semi-Cursive Script Chinese Font.otf" on my hard drive.

The second application is written in PyQt4 and ideally I could use some of the tools in Qt to handle this. For example I can construct a QFont from the font name, and query QFont.exactMatch() to make sure that I get THAT font - and from there I could create a QFontInfo object, however the only useful data I seem to be able to get out of a QFontInfo object is rawName() which just gives me the postscript name again...

From reading around it looks like I could search the registry but I have never worked with the registry and the examples I found were written in C++ which I'm not sure how to translate.

For info this only needs to work on Windows.

Comment: Why do you need the filename? If the font has been installed properly, all applications should be able to load it using only its font-name. (That's kind of the point of the font-names, really).

Comment: I realize it's an odd situation. In a nutshell I'm creating a program for archiving files, and I need to copy the actual font file into the archive. Therefore I need to know what the actual file name is, not the font name

Answer (score 0):

You could use fontTools and matplotlib.

If you need any more information about how to decode the font postscript, see the answer I posted here: [How to get the font name (title) from a font file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417219/how-to-get-the-font-name-title-from-a-font-file-in-python)

```
from matplotlib import font_manager
from fontTools import ttLib

def isFontMatchPostscriptName(fontPath: str, font: ttLib.TTFont):

    postScriptName = font['name'].getDebugName(6)

    if postScriptName == "Cambria":
        print("The font is located in: ", fontPath)

fontsPath = font_manager.findSystemFonts()

for fontPath in fontsPath:

    with open(fontPath, 'rb') as fontFile:
        fontType = fontFile.read(4)

    if fontType == (b'ttcf'):
        # TTC File.
        ttCollection = ttLib.ttCollection.TTCollection(fontPath)

        for font in ttCollection.fonts:
            isFontMatchPostscriptName(fontPath, font)
    else:
        # It will be any TrueType or OpenType file except TTC file
        isFontMatchPostscriptName(fontPath, ttLib.TTFont(fontPath))
```