# How to get the font name (title) from a font file in python

Tags: python, fonts

I want to get the font name (the title present in the description of the font file) in python.

[image]

I looked at the `fonttools` module but could not find any way to extract the title using it.

How can I do this?

Comment: see this: http://www.starrhorne.com/2012/01/18/how-to-extract-font-names-from-ttf-files-using-python-and-our-old-friend-the-command-line.html

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Thanks! I made some changes for python 3 and it worked!

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you could do it with fonttools:

```
from fontTools import ttLib
font = ttLib.TTFont(fontPath)
fontFamilyName = font['name'].getDebugName(1)
fullName= font['name'].getDebugName(4)
```

The number 1, 4 are nameID. If you need anything more, read this documentation about nameID: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/name#name-ids

Here is fonttools documentation about the naming table: https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ttLib/tables/_n_a_m_e.html

If you need a more robust method to get an name from the naming table, you can use this logic:

```
import sys
from fontTools import ttLib
from fontTools.ttLib.tables._n_a_m_e import NameRecord
from typing import List


def sortNamingTable(names: List[NameRecord]) -> List[NameRecord]:
    """
    Parameters:
        names (List[NameRecord]): Naming table
    Returns:
        The sorted naming table.
        Based on FontConfig:
        - https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/fontconfig/-/blob/d863f6778915f7dd224c98c814247ec292904e30/src/fcfreetype.c#L1127-1140
    """

    def isEnglish(name: NameRecord) -> bool:
        # From: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/fontconfig/-/blob/d863f6778915f7dd224c98c814247ec292904e30/src/fcfreetype.c#L1111-1125
        return (name.platformID, name.langID) in ((1, 0), (3, 0x409))

    # From: https://github.com/freetype/freetype/blob/b98dd169a1823485e35b3007ce707a6712dcd525/include/freetype/ttnameid.h#L86-L91
    PLATFORM_ID_APPLE_UNICODE = 0
    PLATFORM_ID_MACINTOSH = 1
    PLATFORM_ID_ISO = 2
    PLATFORM_ID_MICROSOFT = 3
    # From: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/fontconfig/-/blob/d863f6778915f7dd224c98c814247ec292904e30/src/fcfreetype.c#L1078
    PLATFORM_ID_ORDER = [
        PLATFORM_ID_MICROSOFT,
        PLATFORM_ID_APPLE_UNICODE,
        PLATFORM_ID_MACINTOSH,
        PLATFORM_ID_ISO,
    ]

    return sorted(names, key=lambda name: (PLATFORM_ID_ORDER.index(name.platformID), name.platEncID, -isEnglish(name), name.langID))


def get_font_names(font: ttLib.TTFont, nameID: int) -> List[NameRecord]:
    """
    Parameters:
        font (ttLib.TTFont): Font
        nameID (int): An ID from the naming table. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/name#name-ids
    Returns:
        A list of each name that match the nameID code.
        You may want to only use the first item of this list.
    """

    names = sortNamingTable(font['name'].names)

    return list(filter(lambda name: name.nameID == nameID, names))

def main():
    font_path = r"FONT_PATH"
    font = ttLib.TTFont(font_path)

    print(get_font_names(font, 1))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use external tools like [otfinfo](https://www.lcdf.org/type/index.html) to extract font meta.

**otfinfo** reports information about the named OpenType font files.

```
$ otfinfo --info raleway.ttf       
Family:              Raleway Light
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           Raleway Light
PostScript name:     Raleway-Light
Preferred family:    Raleway
Preferred subfamily: Light
```

You can call it using subprocess in python and filter desired result using regular expression.

```
import subprocess
import re

font_file = "/home/user/raleway.ttf"
command = "otfinfo"
params = ["--info"]
result = subprocess.run([command, *params, font_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
font_name_re = re.compile(r"Full name:\s*(.*)")
font_name = font_name_re.findall(result.decode())
print(font_name[0])
```

Output: Raleway Light

Comment: Great workaround but I'd prefer a python-only method. Thanks!